# AWS Glue executors dying

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am reading parquet files from S3 with an AWS Glue DynamicFrame in this way:

```
sources = glue_context\
    .create_dynamic_frame\
    .from_options(connection_type="s3",
        connection_options={'paths': source_paths, 'recurse': True,
                            'groupFiles': 'inPartition'},
        format="parquet",
        transformation_ctx="source")
```

After this operation I am transforming the DynamicFrame fo a Spark DF in order to apply specific Spark functions. Finally wrap again these results in a DynamicFrame and use it to write to Redshift.

What happens is that executors keep dying because of

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task in stage ExecutorLostFailure (executor exited caused by one of the running tasks) 
Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. 
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

This behaviour is spottable from the AWS Glue metrics as well:

[image]

I've already read this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-profile-debug-oom-abnormalities.html) which unfortunately uses a JDBC source (S3 in my case) and suggests to use anywhere the Glue DynamicFrames. But unfortunately I really need to use Spark DF for specific data transformation.

How can I solve the issue of executors which keep dying because of memoryOverhead? Is it Spark related or Glue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuning Spark configurations may help.

I was expecting that from a tool such as AWS Glue was not necessary to tune Spark parameters and that was handled by the platform but unfortunately that's not true.

I passed *Parameters* to the Glue Job using this syntax

**Key**: `--conf` 
**Value**: `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2g`

Furthermore introducing some caching logic and repartitioning helped to keep executors busy. Only problem with caching was OOM, which was solved by passing `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2g` parameter.